# Why am I looking at JSON, not my nice Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I've installed swashbuckle on on a clean asp.net core web api project following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). My startup class is below. You can see I've added `AddSwaggerGen()`, `UseSwagger()` and `UseSwaggerUI()`.

When I visit https://localhost:44334/swagger/v1/swagger.json, instead of seeing the swagger UI I expect, I've got a pile of JSON, starting `{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"MoqOcr"}...`

What am I missing ?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        // sby
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "MoqOcr", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // sby
        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

        });

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to the `.json` file because of the extension at the end of your url `https://localhost:44334/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

Comment: I see now that the url in the screenshot is not the url of the browser, but I still can't find what url I should be using. I've tried a dozen.

Comment: Ok now I see that I've got the swagger ui at the root url, but only in http. If I attack with https, which is the default when I click play, I get the values controller. Looks like I'm just a bit new.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your configuration for Swagger in Startup.cs and there seemed no unexpected thing to setup swagger to me. The only thing that pops in my mind is that you are mistaken the `SwaggerEndpoint` setting which indicates to you (I suppose) that you can access your Swagger UI from that url but it holds a json to build and configure that UI page. Fair enough but you should try `https://localhost:44334/swagger`
or  `https://localhost:44334/swagger/index.html` to see your Swagger UI page. Hope this solves your problem.